# Can I bind a particular project's debug configuration to F11 in FlashBuilder?

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

I'm currently working on a large AS3 system consisting of a core project and several modules which are dynamically loaded by the core project at run time. Often when I'm working on one of these modules, I'll reflexively hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to go into debug mode, but as these projects won't run as a standalone application, they'll open an empty Flash player or browser window, and I have to switch to the progress tab, cancel the launch, open a file from the core project and relaunch.

This is a fairly minor issue that I could get around by remembering to manually click the debug button rather than pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>, but no matter how often it happens, I keep forgetting to do so. It only wastes a few seconds each time, but it's something I do tens, if not hundreds of times a day, and it adds up.

Is there a way I can bind the <kbd>F11</kbd> to the debug configuration for the core project only? If not, is there some way I can configure the modules to delegate launching to the core project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the underlying problem of accidentally launching un-runnable projects by changing the run configuration of these to instead launch the main project.